# WWF components for ASP.NET - any out there to view workflows?

Tags: asp.net, workflow-foundation

we use Windows Workflow Foundation internally on a large data manipulation and loading operation. Some of the workflows are complicated and take, with their sub-workflows - significant time, up to a total runtime for the main workflow of arounr 3-4 hours at the moment. THis is expected.... but it would be nice to be able to see where a workflow is.

We have an ASP.NET front end for the operational users. We would lvoe for them to be able to open a page showing a specific running workflow instance in a visualization with basically presenting a way to see the status of the activities (i.e. which activity executed, which is currently executing). No editing is required here . the idea is purely one of not having a black box 3 hour run. We are writing log entries internally which can be seen, but as always, a picture says more than a thousand words, and a visual presentation would definitly be better for them.

Anyone knows of any suite of components for asp.net (preferably mvc) that can visualize a server side running workflow? Editing is NOT required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perhaps not exactly what you are looking for...

I am not aware of any ready-made components but perhaps you can built one for your self using WF designer. See [this sample](http://www.masteringbiztalk.com/blogs/jon/PermaLink,guid,28601754-c305-4597-a0a6-48f32be1eddb.aspx) that hosts workflow designer on server side, capture the image and shows it on the page. It uses custom tracking services to depict which activity has run. Unfortunately, its a dated article and I am not sure if similar approach can work in .NET 4 (AFAIK, workflow designer has changed in .NET 4).

In case designer can not be hosted then you may try painting workflow activities/nodes by custom code. You have to use tracking to see the workflow state.

Comment: This actually was our fallback scenario so far ;) Just loking and hoping for something a little better ;)